# Issue with lapply using biomart

Tags: r, bioinformatics, lapply, biomart

I am trying to use lapply to change the species name when extracting all the human genes.

I'm still learning how to use lapply, I cant work out what I'm doing wrong.

So far I have:

```
library(biomaRt)
```

I create the marts:

```
ensembl_hsapiens <- useMart("ensembl", 
                        dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
ensembl_mmusculus <- useMart("ensembl", 
                     dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
ensembl_ggallus <- useMart("ensembl",
                       dataset = "ggallus_gene_ensembl")
```

Set the species:

```
species <- c("hsapiens", "mmusculus", "ggallus")
```

I then try to use lapply:

```
species_genes <- lapply(species, function(s) getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", 
                                                  "external_gene_name"), 
                                   filters = "biotype", 
                                   values = "protein_coding", 
                                   mart = paste0(s, "_ensembl")))))
```

It gives me an error message saying:

> Error in martCheck(mart) :    You must provide a valid Mart object. To
>   create a Mart object use the function: useMart.  Check ?useMart for
>   more information.

Comment: Been a while since I used `r`, but does the `mart` arg need the actual variable names? You could try `paste0("ensembl_", s)`...

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007584/biomart-is-there-a-way-to-easily-change-the-species-for-all-of-my-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
species_genes <- lapply(species, function(s) getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", 
                                                                  "external_gene_name"), 
                                                   filters = "biotype", 
                                                   values = "protein_coding", 
                                                   mart = get(paste0("ensembl_", s))))
```

Explanation:

the `mart` argument in `getBM` functions expects an object of class `Mart` and not a `string`

```
class(ensembl_ggallus)
#output
[1] "Mart"
attr(,"package")
[1] "biomaRt"
```

by using

```
paste0("ensembl_", s)
```

you get a string such as:

```
"ensembl_hsapiens"
```

the `base` function `get` searches for an object in the environment by name.

```
get("ensembl_hsapiens") 

identical(get("ensembl_hsapiens"), ensembl_hsapiens)
#output
TRUE
```