# Another issue with lapply and BioMart

Tags: r, bioinformatics, lapply, bioconductor, biomart

I recently asked a question about lapply, but now I've changed my approach and ran into more problems I can't resolve.

This is the code I'm having issues with:

Load biomaRt

```
library(biomaRt)
```

Make the hsapiens mart

```
ensembl_hsapiens <- useMart("ensembl", 
                        dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
```

I then extract the human genes:

```
hsapien_PC_genes <- getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_name"), 
                      filters = "biotype", 
                      values = "protein_coding", 
                      mart = ensembl_hsapiens)

ensembl_gene_ID <- hsapien_PC_genes$ensembl_gene_id
```

Set the species vector

```
species <- c("mmusculus", "ggallus")
```

This all works as expected, I run into problems when I use lapply

```
all_homologues <- lapply(species, function(s) getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", 
                                                               "external_gene_name", 
                                                               get(paste0(s, "_homolog_ensembl_gene")), 
                                                               get(paste0(s, "_homolog_associated_ensembl_gene")), 
                                                               filters = "ensembl_gene_id", 
                                                               values = c(ensembl_gene_ID), 
                                                               mart = ensembl_hsapiens)))
```

I get the error message:

```
 Error in martCheck(mart) : 
  You must provide a valid Mart object. To create a Mart object use the function: useMart.  Check ?useMart for more information.
```

The code works perfect like this:

```
all_homologues <- getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_name",  
                               "mmusculus_homolog_ensembl_gene", 
                               "mmusculus_homolog_associated_gene_name"),
                           filters = "ensembl_gene_id",
                           values = c(ensembl_gene_ID),
                           mart = ensembl_hsapiens)
```

But I have many species, so I want to be able to use a small bit of code to extract the homologues for the species, rather than have to rewrite it all for each species.

I think I'm doing something wrong with lapply as the mart works perfectly when not using lapply.

My previous question: 
[Issue with lapply using biomart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031525/issue-with-lapply-using-biomart)

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it, I've managed to get it to work by using:

```
all_homologues <- lapply(species, function(s) getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id", 
                                                               "external_gene_name", 
                                                               paste0(s, c("_homolog_ensembl_gene",
                                                                           "_homolog_associated_gene_name"))),
                                                filters = "ensembl_gene_id",
                                                values = c(ensembl_gene_ID),
                                                mart = ensembl_hsapiens))
```

Although I'm not exactly sure why?